# How to secure refresh token API's?

Tags: authentication, android, rest, api

I have two API's used in `auth`:

1. `api/auth/newtoken`: Successfully validates user (i.e. username and password check in DB) and return `token` (expirers in 3 days) and `refreshToken`.
2. `api/auth/updatetoken`: When the token is expired call this API with `refreshToken` and get the new `token`.

How can I protect the `api/auth/updatetoken` API? Currenlty these API's are for an Android application and it will be easy to get these API's once we decomplile the application.

What are some better approaches to secure this API?

Comment: Not sure what you are worried about here? That someone will find out the URL for `updatetoken`? Doesn't it check that the `refreshToken` is valid anyway?

Comment: The main purpose of refresh tokens is when there is a third party that is providing claims which may change over time. It doesn't sound like that is the case here?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to "protect" the API unless you control all devices which can connect to it. For an API allowing use by user owned devices connecting over the internet then you must assume anyone can send anything to it.

You have two choices here -

- Don't expire the tokens and scrap the uptatetoken call.
- updatetoken requires an existing valid token. If it has expired then newtoken has to be called again and the user has to reauthenticate.

Personally if there is no web browser client (and even with one - just I would give web browser clients an expiring token) I would suggest the first. The token should only sit on the clients device - stored in the device keychain - so should be secure. Meanwhile if anyone has intercepted it they could just call updatetoken themselves to stop it expiring.